# Почему не работает

Tags: c++, ряды

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int a = 3, b = 5;
long double pi = 4;
while(true){
    pi = pi - (4/a);
    a = a + 4;
    pi = pi + (4/b);
    b = b + 4;
    cout << pi << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

почему не работает?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Как написали, так и работает. А догадываться, как **надо** написать, не зная, что вам надо?... Кстати, e вас бесконечный цикл, потому что каждый раз в `while` вы присваиваете переменной `a` значение `-10`...

Comment: да я хотел что бы он был бесконечныи и мне в падлy писать true.Я уже написал что перед знаком равно там стоить !. Под "неработает" я имею  в виду что он  вообще не  запускается.

Comment: Запускается. выводит, как ему и положено, тройки до полного озверения... - https://ideone.com/pXVCFT

Comment: просто я тупой и не понимаю как 4 - (4/3) + (4/5) - (4/7) + (4/9)... получается 3!!!

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотите получить, и что не получается. На такое ни у кого не будет желания отвечать...

Comment: У Вас происходит целочисленное деление. Напишите `(4.0/a)` и `(4.0/b)`.

Comment: Потому что у вас целочисленное деление, и дает целочисленный результат. `pi += 4./b-4./a;` Только долговато у вас этот ряд будет сходиться...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы хотите вот это:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin, std::cout;

int main()
{
    double pi = 4;
    for(int a = 3;;a+=4)
    {
        pi -= 8./(a+2)/a;
        cout << pi << "\r";
    }
}
```

Только сами посмотрите на сходимость [ряда Лейбница](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)...

Comment: спасибо, но он работает дольше.

Comment: Это он и есть :) - просто я объединил пары членов вместе :)

Comment: да я понял что это он и есть.